# Can I check a transaction history on T-Money Card (South Korea)?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, payment-cards, south-korea

I want to check out the transaction history of my T-Money card, a public transportation card in South Korea. If you want to know the balance, you can just go to a convenience store to ask the clerk for showing it.

But is it possible to check the transaction history?

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: @JonathanReez I want to know when and how much I spent on the public transport. This makes me plan better on when I should recharge.

Comment: @pnuts could you translate and convert to an answer?

Comment: I want the same, but as shown below (in the comments on the answer), I'm not likely to get it.  Consequently, I have taken to writing down the balance every time I use it.  When you enter the metro, you will see a charge of 1250 and a new balance after that.  When you exit, if a short trip, you will see a charge of zero and the same new balance.  For a long trip, you will see the additional fare and correct new balance.  I suspect buses are similar but I only did it once and did not look at the display.  While charging, you can print a before/after balance receipt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you need to register with [T-Money here](https://www.t-money.co.kr/ncs/pct/mbrsintg/ReadIntgJoinPrsnAthn.dev)

> You can view the transaction history of the registered TMC card after signing up TMC homepage. After selecting my T-money, you can check your usage history by selecting the card number and then selecting the period.

Comment: Can you show the original text and its linked page? Seems that your link only points to the top page.

Comment: @Blaszard Hi changed the link to point directly to registration, Travel.SE is non-Korean site, why do you want Korean text back?

Comment: Otherwise there is no way to decide whether it is a correct information or not. If you have the link, you may read it via machine translation.

Comment: It points directly to a registration page that Google cannot translate.  And if I paste the text into Google, the results won't fit in a comment, but they imply that if you aren't Korean, you will have to first either get a IPIN from the Korean credit bureau, or a cell phone registered with "Korea Mobile Certification Co."